# How to change Nginx rewrite rule to Apache?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx

Here is my nginx.conf content:

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {

            rewrite ^/(.*) /index.php/$1 last;

            break;
    }

    rewrite_log on;

    location ~ .*\.svn\/.* { return 405; }

    location ~ .*\.php {
            fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
            include fastcgi.conf;
    }

    location ~* \.(html|shtml|htm|inc|log)$ {
            expires 1m;
    }
    location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
            expires 1m;
    }
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|mpeg|mpg|mov|flv|asf|wmv|avi|ico)$ {
            expires 15d;
    }
```

I changed some of this to Apache like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

But when I hided the `/index.php/` in url, I can't load my static resources( css,js,img.etc),how can I change nginx `location` rule to Apache's?

Comment: it should be `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]` not `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]` you forgot `?`

Comment: I'm not familiar with nginx configuration, but the location parts look like they change the equivalent of `ExpiresByType` and not do any rewriting. Maybe, you must change the references to css, js, img to an absolute address (i.e. with leading slash), but to say for sure, you should clarify what "I cannot load my css,js,img" really means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be
 `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]` **with** `?`

**not**

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi,I try to set rewrite mod with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]` and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]`, the effect is the same. But instead of `httpd.conf` I set the same rewrite rule in `.htaccess`, I solved this problem. ...I don't really know why.

Comment: if you need to put your code into `httpd.conf` you have to put the code into `<Directory></Directory>` check this [blog](http://tltech.com/info/rewriterule-in-htaccess-vs-httpd-conf/) however it's better to add it in `.htaccess` so you don't have to access to
Apache’s core server configuration file which is `httpd.conf`